# How to disable the reporting in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-reports

Is there any way to disable the reporting in TFS.
we know while creating project it create the reporting for the team project
but what if we want this to disable while creating of Team project.
we tried following link but nothing works

https://www.nwcadence.com/blog/disable-reporting-for-a-team-project-collection

Comment: What do you mean when you say "nothing works". What happens when you try? Do you get a specific error message? Also, what version of TFS are you using?

Comment: Hi Daniel i mean to say when trying to set the reporting to disable as mention in link  https://www.nwcadence.com/blog/disable-reporting-for-a-team-project-collection i follow as per the link and even following the steps i see the report is not disabled.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need reporting *at all*, you can disable reporting by logging into your TFS app tier server and disabling reporting under the "Reporting" node.

If you simply don't need reports for a particular project, you can create the team project from the web portal, which will not include reports. This is an option in TFS 2015 and later (possibly 2013, I forget the exact version where this first became an option).

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/admin/add-a-report-server?view=tfs-2018

Comment: Thanks for this we have recreate the report ing part since disable is not allowed